# Teclado android não sobrepõe botões

Tags: android, button, teclado

Em uma das telas da minha aplicação:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando eu abro o teclado o mesmo sobrepõe o botão concluído:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tela que original do Registro de Alimentos

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ja nesta outra tela da aplicação isso não acontece e eu gostaria que acontecesse:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue o codigo da ultima tela:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_registro_alimento"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.joao.vitagochi.RegistroAlimentos">

<TextView
    android:text="Refeição"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:id="@+id/textView7" />

<Spinner
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView7"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:id="@+id/spnR" />

<TextView
    android:text="Horario"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/spnR"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:id="@+id/textView8" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="time"
    android:maxLength="5"
    android:text="HH:MM"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView8"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:id="@+id/horarioAlimento" />

<TextView
    android:text="Alimento"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/horarioAlimento"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:id="@+id/textView9" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:ems="10"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView9"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:id="@+id/edtAlm" />

<TextView
    android:text="Quantidade"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView10"
    android:layout_below="@+id/horarioAlimento"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/edtAlm"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:textSize="16sp"/>


<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:ems="2"
    android:id="@+id/edtQtd"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView10"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView10"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView10" />

<Button
    android:text="CONCLUIDO"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:id="@+id/btnConcluidoAlimento" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/lv"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_above="@+id/btnAddAlimento"
    android:layout_below="@+id/edtQtd" />

<Button
    android:text="Add Alimento"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/btnAddAlimento"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
```

Android Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
package="com.example.joao.vitagochi">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    tools:replace="android:label">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".RegistroAtividades"
        android:label="Registro de Atividades"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" />
    <activity
        android:name=".RegistroAlimentos"
        android:label="Registro de Alimentos"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" />
    <activity
        android:name=".RegistroRotina"
        android:label="Registro de Rotina"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Motivacao"
        android:label="Motivação"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Historico"
        android:label="Historico"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Videos"
        android:label="Videos"
        android:parentActivityName=".Motivacao" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Frases"
        android:label="Frases"
        android:parentActivityName=".Motivacao" />
    <activity android:name=".Audios"
        android:parentActivityName=".Motivacao"
        android:label="Audios"
    />
</application>
```

Comment: Mostra o seu AndroidManifest?

Comment: Editei o post agora esta com o manifest

Answer (score 4):

No `Manifest` adicione a seguinte configuração da `Activity`:

`android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"`

O `android:windowSoftInputMode` é responsável pela forma de interação da janela principal da atividade com a janela que contém o teclado de software na tela. Definindo o valor deste atributo como `adjustPan`, a janela principal da atividade não é redimensionada para criar espaço para o teclado de software na tela. Em vez disso, desloca-se o conteúdo da janela automaticamente para que o foco atual nunca seja sobreposto pelo teclado e os usuários possam sempre ver o que digitam. Normalmente, esse comportamento é menos desejável que o redimensionamento, pois o usuário pode precisar fechar o teclado de software para acessar e interagir com as partes sobrepostas da janela.

Referência: [developer.android.com](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft)

Answer (score 0):

Uma solução é você usar o [`ScrollView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html). Com ele você poderá arrastar a tela para que você possa ver elementos escondidos abaixo do teclado. Geralmente é usado quando possui diversas *views* na mesma tela. Veja um exemplo:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <!-- coloque todo seu código aqui dentro -->

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Para mais detalhes, consulte [a documentação](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html).

Uma outra opção seria você inserir seu botão na sua `Toolbar`, porém se possuir muitas views cairá na mesma situação.

Comment: desculpe a demora amigo, mas eu não quero ver o que tem embaixo, eu so quero q o teclado sobreponha o botão ai depois q a pessoa terminar de digitar e resumir o teclado ela pode dar concluir.

Comment: @JoãoCarlos Então realmente eu não entendi o que quis dizer. Mesmo ainda continuo não entendendo com esse seu comentário. Não está muito claro.

Comment: @JoãoCarlos você quer que seu botão fica alinhado no rodapé do seu layout é isso?

Comment: Eu mostrei nas imagens, mas é o seguinte, quando eu abro o teclado os 2 botões sobem e ficam acima do teclado, tapando o q a pessoa esta digitando no campo Alimento, então eu queria que quando o teclado fosse acionado ele sobreposse os 2 botões deixando assim o campo Alimento totalmente visivel.

Comment: Adicionei mais uma imagem da tela, de uma olhada, acho q vc vai entender.