# Teclado não sobrepõe botão no Relative Layout

Tags: android, android-layout

Bom dia pessoal.
Estou com um problema em meu aplicativo: tenho uma tela de cadastro de dispositivos, conforme imagem abaixo, porém, ao habilitar um campo para digitação, o teclado não sobrepõe o botão:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que me deixou com mais dúvida, é que tenho outro layout em que isso não ocorre:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ambos os botões estão com a mesma codificação:

BOTÃO GRAVA DISPOSITIVO

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_gravaDisp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:text="Gravar Dispositivo"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"/>
```

BOTÃO GRAVA USUÁRIO

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_gravaUser"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:text="Gravar Usuário"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"/>
```

Eu verifiquei em alguns outros posts de que existe uma opção de *adjustPan*, porém, ambas essas classes estendem *Fragment*, não ao *AppCompatActivity*.

Abaixo, código java de ambas as classes:

Cadastrar Dispositivo:

```
public class CadastrarDispositivos extends Fragment {


@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    getActivity().setTitle("Cadastro de Dispositivos");
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup 
container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.cadastrodispositivos, container, 
false);
}

}
```

Usuarios:

```
public class Usuarios extends Fragment {


@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    getActivity().setTitle("Usuários");
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup 
container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.usuarios, container, false);
}

}
```

Xml do cadastro de dispositivos:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/inputNomeDisp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="20dp">
    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/editNomeDisp"
        android:hint="Nome do dispositivo"
        android:textColorHint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:maxLength="20"
        android:inputType="text"/>
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_below="@id/inputNomeDisp"
    android:id="@+id/inputTipoDisp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/editTipoDisp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:hint="Tipo do dispositivo"
        android:textColorHint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:maxLength="20"
        android:inputType="text"/>
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_below="@id/inputTipoDisp"
    android:id="@+id/inputLocalDisp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/editLocalDisp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:hint="Local do dispositivo"
        android:textColorHint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:maxLength="20"
        android:inputType="text"/>
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_below="@id/inputLocalDisp"
    android:id="@+id/inputPortaDisp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/editPortaDisp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:hint="Porta do dispositivo"
        android:textColorHint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:maxLength="20"
        android:inputType="number"/>
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_gravaDisp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:text="Gravar Dispositivo"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"/ 
</RelativeLayout>
```

Xml do cadastro de usuário:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
android:id="@+id/inputNomeUsuario"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:paddingTop="20dp">
    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/editNomeUsuario"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:hint="Nome do usuario"
        android:textColorHint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"/>
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/inputSenhaUsuario"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/inputNomeUsuario">
    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/editSenhaUsuario"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:hint="Senha do usuario"
        android:textColorHint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"/>
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
    android:layout_below="@id/inputSenhaUsuario"
    android:id="@+id/txtAdministrador"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Administrador?"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"/>

<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatCheckBox
    android:id="@+id/cbx_Sim"
    android:text="Sim"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:layout_below="@id/txtAdministrador"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatCheckBox
    android:id="@+id/cbx_Nao"
    android:text="Não"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:layout_below="@id/cbx_Sim"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_gravaUser"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:text="Gravar Usuário"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Desde já agradeço quem puder me ajudar!

Valeu!

Comment: Eu acho que o layout que cobre é um LinearLayout e o que não cobre é um ScrollView

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Teclado android não sobrepõe botões](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/176889/teclado-android-n%c3%a3o-sobrep%c3%b5e-bot%c3%b5es)

Comment: Os dois fragments são adicionados na mesma activity?

Answer (score 1):

Ao que tudo indica, o que está fazendo o botão não ser sobreposto é o item `layout_alignParentBottom="true"`. O que ele faz é literalmente alinhar a view (no caso o botão) com o fim do Layout, de forma que ao aparecer o teclado, o botão vai "subir" junto com o fim do Layout em vez de ser sobreposto.

Um dos dois botões está sendo sobreposto porque essa opção está sendo ignorada. Experimente trocar as duas para "false" e trocar uma por uma para ver os resultados.

Comment: Continuou igual.
Alterei ambos para "false" e ambos foram para o topo da tela. 
1 - Mudei do usuários, e funcionou normal, conforme prints
2 - Mudei do cadastro dispositivos, continuou com o erro acima.

Comment: Verifique as heranças de atributos. Pode ser que estejam diferentes e sobrepondo o que está no XML. Também verifique se não tem nada sendo mudado programaticamente.